# Problema con rad studio Embarcadero 10.2.3

Tags: delphi

Tengo un problema con Rad Studio 10.2.3 version Delphi Commmunity Ed, Tengo instalado .Net Framwork 3.5 comienza bien la instalación pero al final me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> "Problem loading data Cannot load data from the server: Error getting
>   Server Certificate"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cierro la ventana del mensaje y se inicia Rad Studio. Voy a File->new-> other, Customizer cualquier opción únicamente muestra dos opciones Project group y Text File

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo crear un formulario. 
Gracias

Comment: Has intentado comunicarte con el soporte de Embarcadero sobre el particular?

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que la instalación no esté correcta.

Yo trataría de repararla o volver a realizaral (recuerda hacerla con permisos de administrador) y de teneer los prerequisitos que se especifican para la versión instalados en la máquina.

[Installation Notes de Tokyo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Installation_Notes)